# Review link disappeared

Tags: support

I just noticed that the review link at the top of the page disappeared. Why is that? Has the reputation limit for reviewing posts been altered? Or have I been deprived of my reviewing privileges due to misuse or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The First Posts and Late Answer review queues now require 500 reputation points. See [Propose a privilege to sit in the 500 reputation mark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186373/).

Comment: Ah thanks! Makes a lot of sense.